# Better sentence for 'lets go for this time"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence, time

I am in conversation with another person to set up a meeting time. He suggested some time to me and asks me suitability of that time for me. I am good at that time. Below is what I have written to him

> 1 PM suits me as well. Let's shoot for that time.

Now is there better sentence to describe above?

Comment: "See you there". Where I live, we don't do much shooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning is basically clear. That said, using the verb "shoot" in this sense is informal, but far from unheard of. I've mainly heard it used by Americans. Probably more common is using the verb "aim".

Do note however that writing "let's aim for" or "let's shoot for" has the implication that the meeting time either hasn't been settled conclusively or that it would be acceptable for one of you to arrive late. If you wish to make it clear that you expect the meeting to be exactly at that time (give or take the socially-acceptable leeway), then writing "See you there/then" as suggested in the comments is safer.

Comment: Or more common: Let’s plan for 1 pm.

Comment: @Jim That’s slightly less common in my experience, but I’ve heard both a fair bit. Slight distinction in meaning as well.